# Mute the external microphone when a headphone is plugged in?

Tags: audio, microphone, headphone-jack

I'm running Gingerbread on my Samsung Galaxy S II. I dock it on my dash in my car and plug a 3.5mm cord from the phone to my stereo aux input.

I often listen to music from my phone through my car stereo, but when a call comes in and I answer it, there is terrible feedback on the other end because the caller hears both my speakers and the audio from the phone.

Is there anything I can do about this other than to switch to a traditional headset?

Comment: How will you talk on the call with the mic muted?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of e.g. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) -- an automation tool which can react on different situations and handle a lot of things (basically, sometimes I think 80% of questions like "How can I...with Android?" could be answered by "Use Tasker!". Though it doesn't come "cheap", on the developers website you can get a 7-day trial to check first. It's worth every cent of its 5 bucks!).

So with tasker, you do simple math:

```
condition + task = profile
```

For your case, it's probably something like...

### Profile "docked-in-car"

- **Conditions:** (they are *always* connected by AND with Tasker)

  - "headphones plugged"
  - "docked"
- **Tasks:**

  - "audio -> mic mute"
  - optionally: "keyguard off"
  - optionally: "display timeout 0" (as it is connected to a power source, so you can continually see what's displayed)
  - most likely: "start app -> [music-app]".

Save & go. Now, when you dock your SGS2 and plug in the 3.5mm cord, mic should be muted -- and additionally some other nice actions executed.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use **Ultimate Car Dock** until my car started supporting **Android Auto**.  I assume that you can not use Android Auto ?  Because that would sort it out.

I would recommend [Ultimate Car Dock](https://ultimate-car-dock.en.uptodown.com/android).  It also gives you hands-free control of the mobile, if you use a car bracket or stand, or holder.

It allows you to make up screen of actions (and people that you can call or message to)

[image: Screen]

You can add your music player to this or you can use the built in music player

[image: Player]

Comment: Just a note, [Android Auto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Auto) was released in 2015, long after the question was posted.