# Mute Phone Mic when Headphones are Plugged In?

Tags: automation, headphones, microphone

I saw a question similar to mine but it was 7 years old so I'm hoping there may be an update to the [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20462/mute-the-external-microphone-when-a-headphone-is-plugged-in/28233?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C17.9282#28233)

I would like for my Note 9 running Android version 10 to mute the mic on the phone when I have my headphones plugged in. It seems like it takes sound from both areas and I have my phone setting right next to my keyboard. When I am typing while talking, the sound of the keyboard clicks are extremely loud to the listener. I cannot move my phone as the conversations are typically video calls and I am using a wired headphone connection. Additionally, when I talk while in a somewhat noisy area, the phone mic seems to be more sensitive to the background noise and quiets my voice via the headphone.

Comment: If there is a similar question please edit your question and include a link to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You might try an app called Pilfershush.
It takes control of the microphone so that other apps can't use it.

Just remember to turn it off before you try to use the phone for a call.

PilferShush Jammer (Block unwanted use of onboard microphone) - https://f-droid.org/app/cityfreqs.com.pilfershushjammer